# Matrix Calculus and Matrix Derivatives

Tags: matrices, analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, matrix-calculus

Consider a map $f : \mathbb R^{n\times m} \to \mathbb R^{p \times l}$ between matrix spaces, what is the differential of such a mapping? I looked at a really simple example, $\operatorname{id} : \mathbb R^{n\times n} \to \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ given by $\operatorname{id}(X) = X$. Then (in analogy to the the case $f : \mathbb \to \mathbb R$ oder $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$) we should have $d\operatorname{id}(A) = I$ for all matrices $A$, where $I$ is the identity matrix (and $d\operatorname{id}$ denotes the differential, i.e. the best linear approximation map).

Now I read about matrix derivatives, for example on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Other_matrix_derivatives) the derivate of a mapping $F : M(n,m) \to M(p,q)$ between matrix spaces is said to be:
$$
 \frac{\partial\mathbf{F}} {\partial\mathbf{X}}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial\mathbf{F}}{\partial X_{1,1}}  & \cdots & \frac{\partial \mathbf{F}}{\partial X_{n,1}}\\
\vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots\\
\frac{\partial\mathbf{F}}{\partial X_{1,m}} & \cdots & \frac{\partial \mathbf{F}}{\partial X_{n,m}}\\
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
And also in the [Matrix Cookbook](http://www.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/3274/pdf/imm3274.pdf) the basic formula (on page 8) is written as
$$
 \frac{\partial X_{kl}}{\partial X_{ij}} = \delta_{ik}\delta_{lj}
$$
(where $\delta_{ij}$ denotes the Kronecker delta) and this I guess is essentially the derivation formula for the identity map. So If I apply this on the above map $\operatorname{id} : \mathbb R^{n\times n} \to \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ I get an $4\times 4$ matrix
$$
 \begin{pmatrix} 
  \frac{\partial X}{\partial x_{11}} & \frac{\partial X}{\partial x_{21}} \\
  \frac{\partial X}{\partial x_{12}} & \frac{\partial X}{\partial x_{22}}
 \end{pmatrix}
 = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  \frac{\partial \begin{pmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12} \\ x_{21} & x_{22} \end{pmatrix}}{\partial x_{11}} &
 \frac{\partial \begin{pmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12} \\ x_{21} & x_{22} \end{pmatrix}}{\partial x_{21}} \\
 \frac{\partial \begin{pmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12} \\ x_{21} & x_{22} \end{pmatrix}}{\partial x_{12}} &
 \frac{\partial \begin{pmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12} \\ x_{21} & x_{22} \end{pmatrix}}{\partial x_{22}}
 \end{pmatrix}
  = \begin{pmatrix} 
     1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
     0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}          
$$
(where I on the last line had not written out the blockmatrices). But this result is quite different from what I would intuitively expect, so what did I wrong? Maybe I am interpreting all these matrix derivatives wrong, could someone please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you first need to pick a basis before you write out the matrix representation of the derivative. The matrix above doesn't make sense
as a derivative.

In general, I find it a little easier to avoid indices, if possible. Dealing
with indices and bases can add unnecessarily clutter.

In the above case, we have $F(X) = X$, so $F(X+H) = X+H$, and so
we see that $DF(X)(H) = H$.

Note that this is a map $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, so if you want to express the derivative as a 
matrix, you need to pick a basis first. The resulting matrix will be a $n^2 \times n^2$ matrix and it will necessarily be the identity
matrix, of course, since $DF(X)(B_k) = B_k$ for the basis elements.

If one uses the inner product induced by the Frobenius norm, then one can
write $\nabla F(X) = I$.

If $\phi(X) = [X]_{kl}$, a similar analysis shows that $D \phi(X)(H) = [H]_{kl}$, and to obtain the component along the $E_{ij} = e_ie_j^T$ direction, we look at $D \phi(X)(E_{ij}) = [E_{ij}]_{kl} = \delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}$.

Comment: If I got your answer correctly it says that in this case, the collection of the partial derivatives (which you mention in your last sentence) did not yield in any natural way the representation matrix, in **sharp contrast** to the case $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$, where the Jacobian (the collection of the partial derivatives) is exactly the representation matrix w.r.t. the standard basis? And for your remark "The matrix above doesn't make sense as a derivative", could it be meaningfully interpreted in any other way if it has nothing to do with the derivative?

Comment: @Stefan: Well, **very** loosely, the matrix should be something like $\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial X}{\partial x_{11}} & \frac{\partial X}{\partial x_{12}} &  \frac{\partial X}{\partial x_{21}} & \frac{\partial X}{\partial x_{22}}  \end{bmatrix}$, if you see what I mean (that is, a 'row' vector rather than a $n \times n$ matrix). To talk about the partials, you must pick a basis first. You can see from this that you will get the identity matrix.

Comment: Okay, the matrix as written above has something to do with the projection maps $\phi(X) = [X]_{kl}$, i.e. how they behave on $\{ E_{ij} \}$, but then why should writing it as a row vector is more natural... guess in some sense I got the point, but it stil feels so artificial and arbitrary, if you have some motivational remarks as why to consider such matrix derivatives I would be thankeful. But nevertheless my question is answered in some sense.

Comment: @Stefan: Well, for functions like the identity, using partials is 'unnatural' in the sense that it forces you to take a pick a basis & compute, whereas the derivative follows naturally from the map itself. The row vector is not natural as such, but when you pick a basis, the corresponding representation of the function is a map $\mathbb{R}^{n^2} \to \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, and an element of $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ (or its dual) is a column/row.

Comment: @Stefan: The projection maps can be used as long as you take the 'standard' basis $E_{ij}$. The representation of the derivative as a matrix of partials means that a basis has already been chosen. Note that, for example, (and **very** roughly) we have $\frac{\partial X}{\partial x_{12}} = (0,1,0,0)^T$, where I am assuming that $E_{12}$ is the second entry in an ordered basis.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of a function $A \rightarrow B$ is a function $A \rightarrow Lin(A,B)$ that for each $x$ in $A$ gives a linear approximation to the function at $x$. So in your case that's $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \rightarrow Lin(\mathbb{R}^{n\times n},\mathbb{R}^{n\times n})$. Since your $id$ function is already linear, the approximation at any point is just the function itself. Your block matrix is just the matrix way of writing $id$ itself. The top left 2x2 block says that the top left corner of the result of id(X) is simply equal to the top left corner of X, and similar for the other 2x2 blocks. That block matrix notation is very confusing though (the indices should be transposed too, i,j instead of j,i).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you explain a little bit more. As I see it, if $f = id$, then $df$ is the identity of $L(R^{2\times 2}, R^{2\times 2})$, and by fixing the indices it should have the representation matrix $$ \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&1\end{pmatrix} $$but if I fix a basis the identity mapping always has as representation matrix the identity matrix?? In any basis, so why not here...

Comment: This is the identity matrix in disguise, the indices are just permuted.

Comment: But as a reprentation matrix of an endomorphism with a fixed base it does not represent the identity transformation...

Comment: Yes, the basis of the domain and the range are permuted.

Comment: As I understand copper's answer this matrix could not reasonably interpreted as a representation matrix (in general, so also in case we are not looking at the identity transformation), or am I wrong?

Comment: You're not wrong, but this does not contradict my previous statement. If you use the same basis for the domain and range the 4x4 matrix would look like the identity matrix you expect.